# Is there any way to measure the number of errors introduced by copy/pasting code?

Tags: language-agnostic, copy-paste

I think copy/paste is one of the worst practices there could be in the industry.

Copy and paste code snippets it's ok. That's how most of the code is learn in first place, and saves a lot of time.

What is definitely harmful ( at least  from my point of view ) is to copy one section of code from a class or file within THE SAME PROJECT!. Pieces of code that are perform almost the same thing, but that have subtle  changes in one or two lines.

The problem comes when after a few months in production or still in beta, a change has to be introduced. Since they are not the same code, you cannot apply the same change, or for some reason the same patch doesn't seems to work ( until after a few hours, you realize, a intermediate call is performed or something like that )

While this is my feeling about the topic, I don't really know if there is an study about it, or something related.

Q.

Does anyone have a reference/paper/article/study or whatever talking about damage produced by copy/paste code?

Related:

[Is copy-and-paste coding ever acceptable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401856/is-copy-and-paste-coding-ever-acceptable/401863)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181549/how-often-do-you-make-errors-by-copying-and-pasting-code

Comment: If you are copying/pasting code within the same project, you should probably instead consider refactoring and pulling the code out into a function.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I say. And you should parametrize all the tiny things that change between them.

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490884/why-is-copy-and-paste-of-code-dangerous

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [interesting discussion](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?CopyAndPasteProgramming) of the issue, with some colorful synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

[Andy Hunt and Dave Thomas on the DRY principle](http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html)

[Sometimes I Repeat Myself](http://www.oh-onemorething.com/essay/)

I recommend trying out a static analysis tool like [CPD from PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html).

Comment: Well presumably no one would post an answer that they thought was worth a downvote. So if that were the criteria for downvoting, no one would ever get any.

Comment: True enough. A couple more downvotes and I can get a badge for deleting it!

Comment: This only shows the number of duplications it doesn't show the damage produced by copy/paste code as was asked.

Comment: @Daniel I'd argue that it successfully "measure[s] the number of errors introduced by copy/pasting code?"

Comment: @Instantsoup:  On the grounds that having any copy-pasted code is an error, since while it might work now it's a maintenance disaster waiting to happen?  I can sympathize with that.